# Input variables as stored procedure statement

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, variables, stored-procedures

My stored procedure:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[Perdate]
@D_Data as nvarchar(999) 

AS

SELECT    'Total'=  SUM(CAST(TBL_Stock.R_TotalPrice  as decimal(18,2))),(convert(varchar,TBL_Stock.D_Datepush,105)) as Date
FROM       TBL_Stock 
GROUP BY  (convert(varchar,TBL_Stock.D_Datepush,105)) 
Having     (convert(varchar,TBL_Stock.D_Datepush,105)) = @D_Data
```

I would like to know if it is possible to set that variable (`@D_Data`) as something like:

```
 '02-03-2012' or  (convert(varchar,TBL_Stock.D_Datepush,105)) = '02-04-2012'
```

So the having clause would be :

```
 HAVING (convert(varchar, TBL_Stock.D_Datepush, 105)) = '02-03-2012' 
        OR (convert(varchar, TBL_Stock.D_Datepush, 105)) = '02-04-2012'
```

So my idea is to have (in my VB.net project) a string that could dynamically change the stored procedure "Future"

Comment: I don't have time to give a full answer, but one thing is: why use HAVING when it doesn't contain an aggregate? Put the condition in a WHERE clause! Also, what DBMS and what version? Microsoft SQL Server 2008 or what?

Comment: You'll want to look into dynamic sql. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188001.aspx. If you go that route you'll lose a lot of benefits of using stored procedures such as plan caching. Chances are is that there is a better solution for what you are trying to do, so what is it that you really want to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like you want to do SQL injection so that your input param "glues into" the TSQL that is being built in your proc. THIS IS A VERY BAD IDEA ( [see SQL Injection discussion here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection)).

But good news, dynamic SQL is not needed. Use a table function to parse the incoming string so that it can be joined in the proc.

```
create table TBL_Stock(R_TotalPrice decimal(18,2), D_Datepush datetime)
insert into TBL_Stock(R_TotalPrice,D_datepush) values(1000,'1/1/2012')
insert into TBL_Stock(R_TotalPrice,D_datepush) values(200,'1/2/2012')
insert into TBL_Stock(R_TotalPrice,D_datepush) values(30,'1/3/2012')
insert into TBL_Stock(R_TotalPrice,D_datepush) values(4,'1/4/2012')
GO

CREATE FUNCTION dbo.SplitDates(@String varchar(8000), @Delimiter char(1))     
returns @temptable TABLE (dt datetime)     
as     
begin     
    declare @idx int     
    declare @slice varchar(8000)     

    select @idx = 1     
        if len(@String)<1 or @String is null  return     

    while @idx!= 0     
    begin     
        set @idx = charindex(@Delimiter,@String)     
        if @idx!=0     
            set @slice = left(@String,@idx - 1)     
        else     
            set @slice = @String     

        if(len(@slice)>0 AND isDate(@slice) = 1)
            insert into @temptable(dt) values(@slice)     

        set @String = right(@String,len(@String) - @idx)     
        if len(@String) = 0 break     
    end 
return     
end
GO

--test function
select * from dbo.SplitDates('1/1/2012,1/2/2012',',')
GO

create PROCEDURE Perdate @D_Data as nvarchar(2000) 
AS
select
    PushDate=z.dt,
    'Total'=  SUM(s.R_TotalPrice)
from 
    dbo.splitDates(@D_Data,',') z
    join TBL_Stock s on s.D_datepush = z.dt
group by
    z.dt
GO

--Test proc
select * from TBL_Stock
exec Perdate '1/1/2012'
exec Perdate '1/1/2012,1/2/2012'
exec Perdate '1/1/2012,1/4/12'
```

[image]

Comment: That was genius @sisdog. The idea that you provided me was not exactly what I wanted BUT all the code helped me so much and finally I could resolve this issue. Thanks